# System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

I don't know why this error occurs. Here is my code.
I built it. "Debug build". When I clicked the login button, phone's screen turned black and app didn't respond.
**System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.**

```
    etEmail = findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

    Email = etEmail.getText().toString();
    Password = etPassword.getText().toString();

    mFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password).addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                uid = mFirebaseAuth.getUid();
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, CalendarActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("firebaseUID", uid);
                sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("file", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.clear();
                editor.commit();
                editor.putString("email", Email);
                editor.putString("password", Password);
                editor.putString("google", "no");
                editor.commit();
                startActivity(intent);

                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                finish();
            }
            else {
                //Login Failure
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email or Password is not correct.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: I don't know what doesn't work and why it doesn't work. I want this to work properly. This Firebase Login method doesn't work. When I launched this app(Debug Build), my phone's screen turns black.

Comment: In logcat, there's an error.
-System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null